# JavaFX Import Error for javafx.builders package

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, javafx

I am learning JavaFX from Pro Java FX 2 book. I am trying to import javafx.builders.* package. but compiler keeps raising errors import cannot be resolved. but other packages javafx.* excepts javafx.builders.* imports successfully. I am using JavaSDK 7u51. I tried in eclipse with e(fx)clipse and Netbeans as well. Please help me to find solution.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such package as `javafx.builders`. Each builder is (generally) in the package of the class it builds, for instance `GroupBuilder` is in `javafx.scene`, as:

```
import javafx.scene.GroupBuilder;
```